# docker: 'compose' is not a docker command in Windows 10. How to run?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

How to run docker-compose in Windows 10? I am getting compose is not a docker command.

```
> docker-compose
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
```

Please help. I tried with Docker Desktop version 4.26.1 and 4.22.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The command is `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose` since the V2 of compose

https://docs.docker.com/compose/migrate/

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried both.